# Odd behaviour with fulltext potgresql search in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, full-text-search, pg

I have followed the [Full-Text Search in PostgreSQL Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/343-full-text-search-in-postgresql) but I am getting some odd behaviour.

For example, when I search 'police' I don't get any results, but when I search 'polic' I do. (Police exists in the content I am searching). It is also not returning some results at all - yet I know the word exists, whether the word is large or small.

When I start rails dbconsole it says I am using psql (9.1.4),and the rest of the app seems to be functioning as normal too.

Do I need to rebuild indexes or something?

I am using the PG gem, and the postgres_ext gem, I am not using the texticle or pg_search gems (as I don't really need the added features).

My code is otherwise the same as per the screencast:

```
def self.text_search(query)
  if query.present?
    rank = "ts_rank(to_tsvector(name), plainto_tsquery(#{sanitize(query)}))"
    where("to_tsvector('english', name) @@ :q 
           or to_tsvector('english', content) @@ :q", q: query).order("#{rank} desc")
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

And I have created the indexes as such:

```
class AddSearchIndexToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute "create index articles_name on articles using gin(to_tsvector('english', name))"
    execute "create index articles_content on articles using gin(to_tsvector('english', content))"
  end
end
```

Interestingly, if I remove the call to to_tsvector in the where call:

```
def self.text_search(query)
  if query.present?
    rank = "ts_rank(to_tsvector(name), plainto_tsquery(#{sanitize(query)}))"
    where("name @@ :q 
           or content @@ :q", q: query).order("#{rank} desc")
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

...it works as expected (apart from being very slow as the indexes seem to be getting ignored)

Any ideas what's going on?

Update:

After switching on full logging, here is the sql being run:

```
LOG:  statement: SELECT 1
LOG:  statement: SELECT  "dogs".* FROM "dogs"  WHERE (to_tsvector('english', name) @@ 'wary' 
               or to_tsvector('english', other_names) @@ 'wary'
               or to_tsvector('english', origin) @@ 'wary'
               or to_tsvector('english', kusa) @@ 'wary') ORDER BY         ts_rank(to_tsvector(name), plainto_tsquery('wary'))
     desc LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
LOG:  statement: SELECT 1
LOG:  statement: SELECT 1
```

I'm no sql expert but the query looks ok?

Also, I'm not sure if it's relevant but there's also a lot of these in the log file:

```
FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 821) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?
```

I installed postgres via homebrew, and am using 9.1.4

Comment: Have a look at the underlying SQL your app is running. Set `log_statement = 'all'` in `postgresql.conf` and restart Pg or `pg_ctl reload`. Re-run the problem code and examine the logs. Also: In future please mention the versions of what you're using, especially PostgreSQL, as it can make a difference.

Comment: Hi Craig, thanks for the reply. I have updated the question with the additional info. If you need any other details - just let me know, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider how the word *police* is transformed by `to_tsvector`:

```
select to_tsvector('english','police');
```

results in:

```
 to_tsvector 
-------------
 'polic':1
```

If we compare that directly with *police* , it's not going to match:

```
select to_tsvector('english','police') @@ 'police' as match;
```

results in:

```
 match
----------
 f
```

(f is the boolean **false** in this context).

But if the comparison is made against the result of `plainto_tsquery`, then it does match:

```
select to_tsvector('english','police') @@ plainto_tsquery('english','police')  as match;
```

results in:

```
 match 
-------
 t
```

Conclusion: don't match a tsvector directly with a word, match it with the result of `plainto_tsquery`, or `to_tsquery`.

---

There's also something else that you may want to tighten: currently you query contains both `to_tsvector` calls with the *english* configuration explicitly passed to it, and calls without this argument (in the `ORDER BY` clause), in which case it defaults to the current value of the `default_text_search_config` parameter.
If and when this parameter is different from *english*, that may yields unexpected results with certain expressions. It's better to either consistently pass this parameter, or consistently omit it. The latter case has the advantage of brevity and avoids hard-coding a specific language.